# Как установить Sass и Compass (для чайника)?

Tags: sass

[На сайте sass](http://sass-lang.com/install) написано, что нужно в начале установить Ruby. Установил с помощью [RubyInstaller](http://www.rubyinstaller.org/). Далее надо с помощью командной строки установить собственно sass и [compass](http://compass-style.org/install/). Как это сделать? Это же не та командная строка, что в Windows изначально стоит, как я понимаю. И как после этого начать работать с Sass и Compass тоже непонятно..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Та самая командная строка.

```
d:\> gem update --system
d:\> gem install compass
d:\> compass create myproject
d:\> cd myproject
d:\myproject> compass watch
```

дальше создаете в `d:\myproject\sass` свой какой-нибудь `style.scss`, например:

```
@import "compass";
$base-border-radius: 5px;
$base-color: #000066;
$highlight-color: lighten($base-color, 50);
div {
  @include border-radius($base-border-radius);
  color: $base-color;
  &.highlight {
    color: $highlight-color;
  }
}
```

и в `d:\myproject\stylesheets` создастся `style.css` и будет меняться при каждом изменении (сохранении) `style.scss`. получится такой результат:

```
/* line 5, ../sass/style.scss */
div {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #000066;
}
/* line 8, ../sass/style.scss */
div.highlight {
  color: #6666ff;
}
```

в `config.rb` соответственно есть настройки куда сохранять `css` файлы (`css_dir`), сжимать `css` или добавлять комментарии (`output_style`) и т.д.

Comment: дальше можно сходить за готовыми рецептами http://compass-recipes.moox.fr/

Comment: Когда я начинаю прописывать в командной строке, мне выдаёт

"gem" не является внутренней или внешней командой, используемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: пути надо прописать до c:\ruby<тут  номер версии какой-то>\bin  
см например здесь [Не работают команды в cmd](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/26486f2a-2048-40c1-963f-166dc303b421/-cmd?forum=vistaru)

Answer (score 1):

Если для чайников, то почему бы не использовать готовые приложения?

Например: [compass.app](http://compass.kkbox.com/)

Скачали, распаковали, запустили и указали папку которую нужно слушать. Все)))

Есть только 2 нюанса:

1. Создать config.rb ручками, либо через меню приложения
2. В винде - адрес к приложению и к слушаемой папке не должен содержать кириллицы. Иначе при компиляции ruby будет ругаться)