# CSS не обновляется после изменения _scss файлов

Tags: ruby, css, sass

Начала изучать SASS и столкнулась с проблемой. Просмотр официальной документации и инета пока результатов не дал.

Проблема в следующем.

Есть папка "bootstrap", в которой собраны все модульные  файлы с расширением _scss. 
Папка "bootstrap" вложена в папку "css". В папке "css" есть также  файл bootstrap.scss, в которой импортированы все файлы _scss. и скомпилированный файл css.

1. На компьютер установлен ruby и gem sass.
2. В командной строке пишу sass b\css\bootstrap.scss b\css\bootstrap.css Файл css компилируется как положено.
3. Чтобы задать автоматическое изменение css файла пишу 
    sass --watch b\css\bootstrap.scss:b\css\bootstrap.css
4. Однако когда я вношу изменения в файл scss или в файл  _scss, то изменения не отображаются автоматически. Чтобы увидеть изменения приходиться снова задавать команду watch

Как мне сделать так, чтобы изменения в файле scss и, в особенности, в файлах _scss, автоматически передавались в скомпилированный css без необходимости снова задавать команду watch. Хочется сразу перезагрузить браузер и увидеть изменения.

Добавлю, что у меня Windows XP (может, глюк OC?). Знаю, что есть спец. программы для этих целей, но все же предпочитаю управлять измемениями с помощью командной строки. 
В документации говориться о том, что можно задать путь к папке sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets  Пытаюсь задать путь sass --watch b\css\bootstrap/sass:b\css/bootstrap.css, но получаю error о том, что не найден путь. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Как установить Sass и Compass (для чайника)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/279649/)**

> В документации говориться о том, что
>   можно задать путь к папке sass --watch
>   app/sass:public/stylesheets Пытаюсь
>   задать путь sass --watch
>   b\css\bootstrap/sass:b\css/bootstrap.css,
>   но получаю error о том, что не найден
>   путь. Подскажите, пожалуйста. в чем
>   может быть проблема?

Проблема в том, что вы не поняли, что нужно сделать.

```
sass --watch b\css\bootstrap.scss:b\css\bootstrap.css
```

Возможно, нужно использовать **compass**:

```
sass --watch --compass --style compressed b\css\bootstrap.scss:b\css\bootstrap.css
```

Если и это не поможет, то почитайте вот эти статьи:

[**Automatic compilation of Sass and HSS files**](http://bjorkoy.com/2008/10/automatic-compilation-of-sass-and-hss/)
[**Automatic compilation of Sass, Less, Stylus, CoffeeScript and More**](http://docs.mixture.io/preprocessors)

Или попробуйте эти приложения:

**[Koala](http://koala-app.com/)** (Guide - [**SASS on Windows Tutorial – Automatic SASS Compilation**](http://bobmckay.com/web/sass-css/sass-windows-tutorial-automatic-sass-compilation))
**[SCOUT](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/)**

Comment: VenZell спасибо за ответ! Но это я уже сделала. (пункт второй в моем вопросе). В вопросе не стоит двоеточие, забыла написать, но в командной строке оно есть. Проблема как раз в том, что при внесении изменений в файл _scss должен АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ!!! обновляться файл scss и компилированный css, а обновляются они ТОЛЬКО ПОСЛЕ ПОВТОРНОГО ВВОДА КОМАНДЫ WATCH. Не будешь же каждый раз вручную вводить команду после каждого изменения.  Вот в чем проблема. Официальную документацию я уже прочитала до того, как задать вопрос,  там ответа на такой баг нет, к сожалению.

Comment: @Olga Moscow, добавил в ответ вариант с использованием watcher'а от  compass. Так должно заработать.  
Если все равно не поможет, добавил альтернативные варианты.

Comment: VenZell, большое спасибо! Через Compass не заработало (только css скомпилировался в одну линию)), попробую скрипты и Koala. Возможно, просто глюк OC, которая уже не поддерживается.